# How can I prevent transforms on Windows Edge?

Tags: css, sass, microsoft-edge

In every other the animations I am using work great.
This is not the case of Windows Edge.

So I want to prevent those animations to fire on Edge.

Here is what I want to prevent:

```
        &:hover:not(.selected-shown) {
            img {
                transform: scale(1.1);
            }
        }
```

That `transform:scale`, how can I point to Edge only on CSS/SCSS?

Comment: use `ms-transform`, maybe, instead of just `transform`?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb no, `ms` only works for versions under Edge, not for Edge itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @supports and test for an Edge specific property. Something like this

```
   &:hover:not(.selected-shown) {
       img {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }
      @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
        img { transform: none; } 
      }
    }
```

Credits to Jeff Clayton's post

https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/css-hacks-for-windows-10-and-spartan-browser-preview/